# Session time out in bot-builder framework?

Tags: botframework

What is the session time-out duration in Microsft bot-builder framework?

To explain it, if my bot asks three questions and I responded to two question and left it unattended then after how much time it will forget the previous state and will prompt the first question again if I ping it?

I have checked it for more than 20 minutes and it resumes the conversation without any state change.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a timeout. The bot will maintain the state unless you clear it.